# determining the cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $S$ be the collection of closed intervals in the real line whose lengths are positive rational numbers. Determine the cardinality of $S$. Justify your answer

As I understand, $S$ will be an infinite set of positive rationals. Would that mean that its cardinality will be equal to $c$?

Comment: There are a lot more of these intervals than there are rationals.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT 1**: Let $C = \{[r,r+1]: r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $C \subset S$.

**HINT 2**: Write $S = \bigcup_n C_n$, where $C_n = \{[r,r+q_n]:r \in \mathbb{R}\}$, where $(q_n)_{1}^{\infty}$ is an enumeration of rationals.

Comment: $C$ is also $\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, so $C\subset S$ does not settle the question of cardinality completely.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Let me know if you need more hints.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a set of intervals, not of rational numbers.

Consider $[x, x+1]$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Are these in $S$?
So what is the minimal and maximal cardinality of $S$?

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is in obvious bijection to $\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q_{>0}$. So you need to be aware that $\mathfrak c\cdot \aleph_0=\mathfrak c$.